# It was raining last night or It had rained last night

Tags: past-tense

In an short story- which tense suits better? Will my writing in the next line depend on which one I choose? For ex.
It was raining last night. Now a little girl was walking along the street....
It had rained last night. Now a little girl walked along the street...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately, "which is better" is going to be a matter of opinion, especially when you have not provided us any context to go on. As such, this question is not well-suited to our format, which is oriented to questions for which a single definitive answer can be given. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

If the action of the story is taking place the morning after the rain, you should use "it had rained".  If the action of the story takes place on the night of the rain, you should use "it was raining".